# Creating a full nltk parse tree from a list of nltk subtrees in python 3.5

Tags: python, parsing, tree, nltk, subtree

I have list of subtrees which I derived from a parse history formatted as follows:

The parse history:

```
parse = [('S', 0), ('NP', 1), ('Det', 0), ('N', 0), ('VP', 1), ('V', 4), ('NP', 2), ('NP', 0), ('PN', 1), ('NP', 1), ('Det', 0), ('N', 3)]
```

Each tuple in the list has a key to a grammar dictionary which contains a list of rules. The second item in the tuple is the index of the rule for that given key.

The grammar is:

```
grammar = {'S': [['NP', 'VP']],
               'NP': [['PN'], ['Det', 'N']],
               'VP': [['V'], ['V', 'NP', 'NP']],
               'PN': [['John'], ['Mary'], ['Bill']],
               'Det': [['the'], ['a']],
               'N': [['man'], ['woman'], ['drill sergeant'], ['dog']],
               'V': [['slept'], ['cried'], ['assaulted'],
                     ['devoured'], ['showed']]}
```

The list of subtrees is:

```
[Tree('S', ['NP', 'VP']), Tree('NP', ['Det', 'N']), Tree('Det', ['the']), Tree('N', ['man']), Tree('VP', ['V', 'NP', NP]), Tree('V', ['showed']), Tree('NP', ['PN']), Tree('PN', ['Mary']), Tree('NP', ['Det', 'N']), Tree('Det', ['the']), Tree('N', ['dog'])]
```

I created the list of subtrees using the following code:

```
for item in parse:
        apple = Tree(item[0], grammar[item[0]][item[1]])
        trees.append(apple)
```

The output I got when I printed the trees (which I know isn't the correct method but it at least shows the subtrees) is as follows:

```
(S NP VP)
(NP Det N)
(Det the)
(N man)
(VP V NP)
(V showed)
(NP NP NP)
(NP PN)
(PN Mary)
(NP Det N)
(Det the)
(N dog)
```

Thanks for the help!

::EDIT::

The correct output should look like this:

```
(S(NP(Det the)(N man))(VP(V showed)(NP(PN Mary))(NP(Det the)(N dog))))
```

Comment: Please show the tree that you are trying to generate.

Comment: @alexis The tree should look like this:

    (S(NP(Det the)(N man))(VP(V showed)(NP(NP(PN Mary))(NP(Det the)(N dog)))))

Comment: Put it in your question.

Comment: Very good. Now your question gives enough information to be understood and answered.

Comment: Now here's how you make your tree: Each of your mini-trees has two strings as the leaves. Replace them with the tree that you build when you apply the next rule in your parse history. Work on it and you'll probably find it's easier to assemble the tree from the bottom up, which is why @randomsurfer's answer says you need to do it recursively. You can use that code as a starting point. But work on it. I don't know if this homework or for your own education, but it won't do you any good to have it written for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recursively build the tree, but you need to distinguish between terminals and non-terminals. Btw. your parse sequence seems wrong. I hacked this up:

```
def build_tree(parse):
  assert(parse)
  rule_head = parse[0][0]
  rule_body = grammar[rule_head][parse[0][1]]
  tree_body = []
  rest = parse[1:]
  for r in rule_body:
    if non_term(r):
        (subtree,rest) = build_tree(rest)
        tree_body.append(subtree)
    else:
        tree_body.append(r)

  return (tree(rule_head,tree_body), rest)
```

Comment: Does this one look better?

    [('S', 0), ('NP', 1), ('Det', 0), 'scan', ('N', 0), 'scan', ('VP', 1), ('V', 4), 'scan', ('NP', 2), ('NP', 0), ('PN', 1), 'scan', ('NP', 1), ('Det', 0), 'scan', ('N', 3), 'scan']

Comment: I mean your initial input seems to be wrong. Try to recursively build a tree, and you'll find out where its wrong

Comment: Detecting terminals is easy: they are not keys in `grammar`.

Comment: @randomsurfer_123 Can you explain how the part under:

if non_term(r):

works? I don't understand the subtree part. Thanks

Comment: @GianpaulRachiele Basically you need to build a subtree for a non-terminal, in the process it will consume a bunch of your subtree stumps. So the recursion should return the tree that you just built, and the remaining part of the input, so you can recurse on the next non-terminal.

Comment: @randomsurfer_123 The biggest problem I am having is the depth of the trees. I seem to be able to get from the top node 'S' and expand it to ['NP', 'VP'] and then expand the 'NP' to ['Det', 'N'] but I can't get past that